# iOs Safari running wrong function in minified Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, safari

I have an angularJS SPA that is published from Visual Studio using MVC4 bundling to minify most of the scripts. The problem I'm having is that on Safari, the wrong function is being run.

Here are some screen captures to show the issue:
[image: Calling code]

Note the definition of the function, and how it's identified as "v" in the popup available on rollover.

[image: called code]

I've outlined function v in red. You can see in the call stack Safari thinks that's what it's calling. Note the function definition matches the one in the popup. Yet, the line we're stopped on is actually in function d. The yellow lines are causing the bug, so we really need to be in the correct function.

I have no idea what to do about this. I tried renaming both methods, which forced the bundling to happen again, but that did not resolve the issue. Has anyone seen anything like this?

I'm running an iPad mini, but this has been reported on multiple devices.